# "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" issue in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I have saved video file in IsolatedStorage and play it using Media Element in Windows Phone 8. For the first time, it executes very well and run successfully and I am able to play video,

The problem is that, whenever I play for the second time, I am getting error like this:

```
"Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream"
```

See my code :

```
 string mediafile = "asaqwrereertrtyrzxxcvcvvbvbv+qwwezzxzxz";
 byte[] PlayByte = Convert.FromBase64String(mediafile);
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(PlayByte, 0, PlayByte.Length);


 IsolatedStorageFileStream isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(audioName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
 isfStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
 isfStream.Close();
 Uri uri = new Uri(isfStream.Name.ToString());
 MediaElement1.Source = uri;
 MediaElement1.Play();
```

Comment: "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" error most likely means, that you're trying to use the file, that is already used by your application. I suggest you to check, if you've closed the FileStream after you've finished playing your media file.

Comment: @Olter I have used isfStream.Close(); so if I remove it,video is not playing even one time.

Comment: @BinjalShah - MediaElement1 still holds the reference to that stream, so set it no null before trying to write there.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar thats it man..that's working..thank you so much brother.stay blessed!!

Answer (score 1):

It Should be solved by disposing that stream means when the audio stops playing dispose the stream by `isfStream.Dispose();` so it would not throw exception but still the Problem remains You can try Solution given below :

It usually happens when you execute that code block several times concurrently. You end up locking the file. So, you have to make sure you include `FileAccess` and `FileShare` modes in your constructor like this:

```
using(var isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(audioName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,FileAccess.ReadWrite, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string mediafile = "asaqwrereertrtyrzxxcvcvvbvbv+qwwezzxzxz";
 byte[] PlayByte = Convert.FromBase64String(mediafile);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(PlayByte, 0, PlayByte.Length);
        string finalstring = stream.ToString();

        **MediaElement1.Source = null;**
            IsolatedStorageFileStream isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(audioName, FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
            isfStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, stream.ToArray().Length);
            isfStream.Close();
            Uri uri = new Uri(isfStream.Name.ToString());
            MediaElement1.Source = uri;
            MediaElement1.Play();
```